# nested ordered dict iteration failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ordereddictionary, xmltodict

readers note:  this data is initially obtained from XML -- if there is an easier way to get xml directly into mysql database please let me know -- been searching a lot and have not quite found that.

I am attempting to do a for loop through an ordered dict that has ordered dicts within based on the returns I am getting from an API.  the response data roughly looks like the following (after converting from xml)

```
OrderedDict([('@name', 'namex'), 
    ('type', OrderedDict([('member', ['aaa', 'bbb'])])), 
    ('location', OrderedDict([('member', 'ccc')])), 
    ('currency', OrderedDict([('member', 'ddd')])), 
    ('10-k', OrderedDict([('member', 'eee')])), 
    ('market-cap', OrderedDict([('member', 'fff')])), 
    ('revenue', OrderedDict([('member', 'ggg')])), 
    ('sector', OrderedDict([('member', 'www')])), 
    ('risk', OrderedDict([('member', 'xxx')])), 
    ('leverage', OrderedDict([('member', 'yyy')])), 
    ('financials', OrderedDict([('group', OrderedDict([('member', 'zzz')]))])),
```

this has made it challening for me to get my for loop to be happy and go through this, with each item on the left being a columns header and the entire blob being a single row,

should I be trying to do something with regex where I ignore/remove/edit text with sed/awk then try and iterate through?

looking for a recommendation on the next step forward, on a simpler ordered dict my for loop was successful but the api responded nicer with

```
OrderedDict([('aaa', 'bbb'), ('ccc', 'ddd'), ('eee', 'fff'), ('hhh', 'iii')])
```

I have been trying to use https://www.python-course.eu/sql_python.php to learn but it does not have this situation, please let me know if anyone has a better source of info for my learning!

my for loop looks like the following

```
for id, a in enumerate(data_response):
    format_str = """INSERT INTO asdf (id, name, type, location, currency, 10-k, market-cap , revenux, sector, risk, leverage, financials) VALUES ({id}, '{name}', '{type}', '{location}', '{currency}', '{10-k}', '{market-cap }', '{revenux}', '{sector}', '{risk}', '{leverage}', '{financials}');"""
    insert_a = format_str.format(id=id, name=a, type=data_response[a], location=data_response[a], currency=data_response[a], 10-k=data_response[a], market-cap=data_response[a], revenux=data_response[a], sector=data_response[a], risk=data_response[a], leverage=data_response[a], financials=data_response[a])
print(insert_a)
```

my expected results

```
INSERT INTO asdf (id, name, type, location, currency, 10-k, market-cap, revenuw, sector, risk, leverage, financials) VALUES (x, 'namex', 'aaa', '(bbb, ccc)', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff', 'ggg', 'www', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz' )
```

I need to be able to iterate through the 'name' ordered dict then the details under each part of the name and consider that one single loop.

Comment: Can you please show us your relevant code, and the desired result?

Comment: after trying some other for loops I think I have found part of the issue.

the key when iterating is  type, location etc.  but it determines there is only one other value which includes the entire reference --> OrderedDict([('member', ['aaa', 'bbb'])])),   so my real challenge is finding a way to ignore OrderedDict([('member', and only select the last part.